# Do I need to paint my house siding under my deck

Tags: painting, exterior, spray-paint

I have cedar siding on my Seattle home. I am repainting the house now and am wondering if I need to paint the siding that is below the deck level. My deck boards are pretty close together with about a cm gap between boards and the boards come flush and parallel to the side of the house. My deck is about 2 feet off the ground. Do I need to remove a few deck boards to paint the space under the deck? Any articles to support your answer would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Cedar siding, while naturally rot-resistant, depends on a good sealer applied periodically to maintain its surface integrity and appearance. Whether you need to paint depends on the age of the existing finish, the conditions it's subjected to, and other factors not addressed in your post.

The bottom line is that you may extend the life of the siding by refreshing its sealer. Whether that's worth the effort is a judgement call.

Answer (score 1):

Is the paint under the deck still in good shape, many times it is because the sun and rain are deflected by the deck. If the paint appears in good condition not peeling I would not try to do anything under the deck.